# Como fazer com que os botões fiquem com a cor definida no css quando selecionada a row em um datatable

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quando seleciono a row, do meu datatable, o botão excluir fica de cor branca e não obedece à cor verde que informei no css. Quando posiciono o mouse sobr eo botão, o foco desaparece e a cor verde aparece. Parece que é algo relacionado à cor do foco...

HTML/Botão:

```
<div class="btn-group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" role="group"><a data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-excluir-financeiro" title="Excluir"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {    
    color: darkgreen !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

Está ficando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?
Obrigado ;)

Comment: `table.dataTable tbody tr.selected .btn { color: inherit; }` ?

Comment: @ Wallace Maxters, funcionouuuuuuuuu!!! Obrigado mano!! Comenta lá como resposta ;)

Comment: Adicionei como resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja simples. Basta adicionar o `.btn` como "herdeiro" de seu `tr.selected` e aplicar o estilo  no mesmo.

Assim:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected .btn { 
  color: inherit; 
}
```

O `inherit` fará com que o mesmo `color` do `tr.select` seja aplicado em `.btn`.

Answer (score 0):

Se fosse um icone do fontawesome seria só mudar o atributo color:

```css
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected i{
   color: darkgreen;
}
```

porém tem que ver como esta esse icone, se ele for setado como `background` ai vai ter que criar outro icone com a cor `darkgreen` e substituir esse background por esse novo icone com a cor alterada quando for `selected`.

Se fosse um svg poderia ser trocado pelo atributo `fill: darkgreen;`

No seu caso pelo visto ->

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected .wb-trash:before {
    color: darkgreen;
}
```